# SSRS Chart Dataset Grouping Filter Values

Tags: reporting-services, charts, grouping, ssrs-2012

I have to make a Chart like in the following Image. The Values are Tagnames with Datetimes and a Value. The Y-Axis is for the Values und the X-Axis for the Datetime.

To do it I have either 3 Datasets which i can not add to one chart or 1 Dataset with Filters. So may Question what would be best Practise to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a dataset where each row contained a datetime and then a column for each value like this..

```
myDatetime |  BlueValue  | RedValue   | GreenValue
2020-08-28 |  50         | 20         | 10
2020-08-27 |  60         | 40         | 20
```

then you can add a series for each line.

If you have a dataset where each row contains a datetime , a column to identify hte measure and then a single value column like this.

```
myDatetime |  MeasureName | Value
2020-08-28 |  Blue        |  50
2020-08-28 |  Red         |  20
2020-08-28 |  Green       |  10
2020-08-27 |  Blue        |  60
2020-08-27 |  Red         |  40
2020-08-27 |  Green       |  20
```

Then you can add a series group to the chart to group by `MeasureName`

Comment: could you help me also with the second Question?

Comment: You should remove this update to your question and start a new question specifically about the 2nd issue. If the original question has been answered then please mark the answer as accepted.